How to install two gitlab-ce services at the same time on one CentOS server?
I want to install and run 2 Gitlab-ce services simultaneously on a single CentOS server，each on a different access port.
I used docker to install, the first gitlab service started can be accessed normally, but the second gitlab-ce service started can not be accessed, the port of gitlab-ce has been changed, so the configured ports of the two gitlab-ce are not conflicting, I don't know what's the reason. Here is the log of the second gitlab-ce service:
2024-05-31_02:51:43.14079 ts=2024-05-31T02:51:43.140Z caller=collector.go:190 level=error msg="collector failed" name=replication duration_seconds=0.091080688 err="sql: Scan error on column index 0, name \"pg_postmaster_start_time\": converting driver.Value type time.Time ( \"2024-05-31 02:49:41.251414 +0000 GMT\") to a float64: invalid syntax"
2024-05-31_02:51:43.14147 ts=2024-05-31T02:51:43.141Z caller=collector.go:190 level=error msg="collector failed" name=postmaster duration _seconds=0.091748349 err="sql: Scan error on column index 0, name \"pg_postmaster_start_time\": converting driver.Value type time.Time (\"2024- 05-31 02:49:41.251414 +0000 GMT\") to a float64: invalid syntax"

